# use-package: How to skip installing/updating packages which are installed by system package manager?

Tags: use-package, straight.el

I use `use-package` with `straight.el` on NixOS.

Some packages are installed by Nix, such as `evil` and `org-mode`.

I see that `use-package` still clones their repositories and tries to build them.

How to avoid that?

Comment: Generally speaking, the packages that the OS installs may not be as up-to-date as the packages on ELPA/MELPA that `use-package` might install. That might or might not be important to you, but it should be kept in mind.

Comment: If you use Nix, I don't see the point in relying in other package managers, such as `straight.el`. `use-package` only installs packages if you want.